# Facebook app login with a subdomain

Tags: oauth, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

Since the "Use Strict Mode for Redirect URIs" became obligatory I have an issue with my application. It uses the

**user.myapp.com**

schema to allow different users to log inte their "work area". But while the list of the users is dynamic, I cannot modify the Client OAuth Settings every time a new user is added.

Is there any solution to this problem?

What I did was to create a dedicated app.myapp.com subdomain, added it to "Valid OAuth Redirect URIs" list and passed it URL to FB login.

But in this case I am getting

**Cross-site request forgery validation failed. Required param "state" missing from persistent data.**

message (I call FB login from app1.myapp.com, the callback is at app.myapp.com with an intention to redirect back to app1.myapp.com)

Just to clarify: if, for test purposes, I redirect back to app1.myapp.com, everything works great. So the code is correct.